# How to create RecyclerView divided into categories

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with building recycler view.
My task is create such recycler view like in the mockup

[image: Example recyclerview]

> Can somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: Too broad for so . Can you provide a expected arrangement of item with an image. i can not understand from the above one. Maybe i  would think of something.

Comment: This seems combination of horizontal and vertical recycle view with linearlayout manager . If categories are limited 4 or 5 then you can omit vertical one . Other wise go with Vertical With each item as `RecylerView` with horizontal layout manager .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GridLayoutManager` can  be initialized by:

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, nColumns);
```

,where `nColumns` is the number of columns. Just chose the number of maximal columns you have and for the missing items you can make an empty `ViewHolder` as a placeholder.